# google charts dashed line between interpolateNulls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I use Google Charts Line chart and have implement `interpolateNulls = true`. This works great but now I want the line that `interpolateNulls` draws to be dotted.

Is it possible to set `lineDashStyle: [4,4]` just on the `interpolateNulls`? 
Here is some of my code:

```
    var drawChart = function (data, type, firstIsAverage, vAxisHeader) {
    var shift = (firstIsAverage === true) ? 0 : 1;

    var fontname = 'Roboto';
    var fontsize = 14;

    var chartObject = {
        type: type,
        display: false,
        data: data,
        options: {
            chartArea: {
                left: 100, 
                top: 30,
                width: 800,
                height: 240
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: vAxisHeader,
                titleTextStyle: {
                    italic: false
                }
            },
           // lineDashStyle: [4, 4],     //Just want this on the interpolateNulls
            interpolateNulls: true,      //Here is the interpolate
            fontName: fontname,
            fontSize: fontsize,
            legend: 'none',
            colors: colors.slice(shift),
            isStacked: "true",
            fill: 20,
            displayExactValues: false
        },
        formatters: {}
    };
    setAllColumnsVisible(chartObject);

    return chartObject;
};
```

Comment: you can use a [certainty role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#certaintyrole). if that doesn't work out, you may have to customize each `null` point using the [style role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole)...

Comment: Okey thank you WhiteHat. i will check that out.